# Loading custom DLLs instead of original DLLs

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, winapi

**The question below is for educational purposes only and the discussed featured are not meant to alter registered DLLs or develop a malware but for learning and experiencing.**

Recently I've been exploring few methods to load my own custom DLLs instead of an application's original DLLs.
One of the methods that came up was the `<exe>.local` method.

After experiencing with this method a little bit and after I removed the `KnownDlls` entry from the registry I managed to replace some system DLLs with my patched DLLs successfully.

These are the DLLs:

[image]

However, the DLLs are IN the local folder:

[image]

However, there are still some DLLs that insist loading from the `system32` directory, although they are present in the local folder.

Is there any way I can force the DLL's to load from the local folder instead of the system32 folder?

Comment: This is malware. Those DLLs are loaded at process startup.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is not malware. It is a fresh vanilla windows 10 virtual machine.

Comment: Any program that tries to substitute system DLLs Ian malware by definition

Comment: Then why are you trying to replace kernel32.dll which is not an app's dll.

Comment: @WeatherVane there are many legitimate reasons to do so. 1. Use proxy DLLs to monitor API calls. 2. Replace functionality as I wish. 3.  Because some people are enthusiastic to learn and experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I do not support tampering with either the OS or proprietory apps.

Comment: @WeatherVane then why Microsoft enabled that feature at first place?

Comment: What feature are you talking about? `regedit`? *"I managed to replace some system DLLs with my patched DLLs successfully."* No, you managed to alter an app.

Comment: No. the `.local` DLL redirection! (which is recommended by Microsoft for implementing proxy DLLs)

Comment: To allow for patches to 3rd party libraries. Not to replace core system libraries.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with the OP - there are legit uses for this.

Comment: Kernel32 and ntdll are system shared DLLs and they include the PE loader that starts any program. You can't change that, definitely not via KnownDLLs. If you want to intercept/override system calls for a certain application look into a hooking library.

Comment: @dxiv, Well ntdll.dll actually hard-coded load kernel32.dll. But it doesn't mean that `.local` DLL redirection is not possible.

Comment: Who do you think is responsible for `.local` redirection if not the PE loader itself.

Comment: If you know the answer why are you asking

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, If I knew the answer I wouldn't ask. And if I didn't know the answer I wouldn't comment.

Comment: Voting to reopen - it is not unclear what the question is asking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm pretty sure the definition of malware is not "a program that tries to substitute system DLLs".

Comment: @immibis you've reversed the logic. Nobody said that was the definition of malware. And yes the question is unclear. A term that has special meaning here.

Comment: @Aviv You claim that .local redirection is possible here. What do you know that we don't. We say that's impossible because the system loader loads those DLLs. Why don't you use hooking? The reality is that you don't want to do that because you want to foist your bogus DLLs on somebody else's process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what I claimed that there is a chance that it is not impossible. Why do you think that you can force me to use DLL hooking if I don't want to do so? I want to use DLL redirection - a feature supported and recommended by Microsoft to implement DLL redirection - in my machine.

Comment: @Aviv Nobody wants to force you to do anything. It makes sense though to solve your problem by using a technique that works. You seem to claim that redirection is supported for kernel32. Why do you claim that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't claim that. Do you know another way to replace those DLLs?

Comment: @Aviv: David's right with his last two comments.  The MSDN page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600(v=vs.85).aspx is pretty clear that the app.exe.local file changes the behavior of `LoadLibrary` and `LoadLibraryEx`.  `ntdll.dll` and `kernel32.dll` are what provide `LoadLibrary`(Ex), so by chicken-and-egg analysis you can see that they aren't loaded by `LoadLibrary`(Ex), and therefore are not affected by DLL redirection.  In fact, I think you'll find that `ntdll` and `kernel32` aren't loaded into a new process at all, they are in the initial module table.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You said that "a program that tries to substitute system DLLs is malware by definition". That would be true if "malware" is defined as "a program that tries to substitute system DLLs". It would also be true if "a program that tries to substitute system DLLs" was defined as "malware", which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Your post ought to contain an actual question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen. is *Is there any way I can force the DLL's to load from the local folder instead of the system32 folder?* not clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer so much as a rambling, unsourced, brain dump.

It does serve to explain why I am not surprised at your result. This boils down, for me, to the crucial difference between CreateProcess and LoadLibrary, and how Win32 processes work.

Normally, when using LoadLibrary, you are using it from within the process you want the dll to be loaded into. As such, it can take advantage of a whole bunch of in-process context information about activation contexts, dll search paths etc. including knowledge of things like the app.local flag.
All these values are specific to the current process and it is not the job of any other process (or even the Kernel) to track stuff like this.

But, if we look at CreateProcess we can see some problems. When it is initially called, it is called in the context of the launching, not destination, process, so it knows nothing of the destination processes activation context. In fact, the destination process does not exist yet.

The CreateProcess implementation needs to create a NT process, and execute some code in it asap to perform the process load as it doesn't make any sense to instantiate all that per process context stuff in the current process.

But, to do that, there needs to be at least some code in the destination process: The kernel code responsible for parsing the EXE files header, extracting the headers and building the activation contexts that will be used to load the remaining dlls.

This means that, unfortunately for you, kernel32.dll and some dependencies need to be mapped into a process long before that process is capable of building a dll search context, noticing the app.local flag etc.

Comment: It's indeed a bit rambling. Perhaps most importantly, `CreateProcess` doesn't actually do that much work. It kicks off kernel code which then creates the new process, maps a few core DLL's, and then starts running the new process. But all that isn't `CreateProcess`. Have a peek at `NtCreateProcess`

Answer (score -2):

You should look at how the Windows loader works. This is OS version dependent, but some of those DLLs load before your program and the loader always looks for them on a path provided by the system. Look at the sequence by starting your program with WinDbg.